# EOF error with Google + OAuth + Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get the Hello Analytics example running to use OAuth2 to connect to the Google Analytics API with Python. The code I'm using is the example code found here, but with my project client_id and secret.
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/analytics/hello_analytics_api_v3.py

However, I get the following error:
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Searching StackOverflow I see others have had the same problem but there wasn't any answer offered.
[EOF error with Google oauth2client (Python, google-app-engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503307/eof-error-with-google-oauth2client-python-google-app-engine)

I'm a beginner and appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the recently update [Hello Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py) docs. It gives examples for both service accounts and [installed](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-py) apps in Python.